# Interface or Class for a list of static finals?

Tags: java, interface, iterator, constants

I am maintaining some Java code that utilizes an interface (let's call it BunchOfConstants) to simply store an abundance of public static final Strings. Occasionally these string names change or string names are added / removed. (which causes a bit of a headache for maintanance)

The only current use for this interface is to compare to input later in a big ugly if/then construct like this:

```
if(BunchOfConstants.CONSTANT1.equals(whatImLookingFor)){
    doSomeStuff(whatImLookingFor)
}else if(BunchOfConstants.CONSTANT2.equals(whatImLookingFor)){
    doSomeStuff(whatImLookingFor)
}else if(BunchOfConstants.CONSTANT3.equals(whatImLookingFor)){
    doSomeStuff(whatImLookingFor)
}
...
```

I thought it would be more elegant to create a class that implements Iterable or even a class that stores this data in a hashMap.

I can not figure out why the original developers decided to use an interface for this design as the interface is never actually implemented anywhere. Does anyone have any input?

Would you agree that an iterable class with these members as constants would be more appropriate?

Comment: Anyway to contact the original developers and ask them why? I admit that a huge if/then is primitive, but i get the feeling either the original developers tried it themselves and hit a bump or they just didn't know a better way...

In short, try out the iterable class and see if it works (better).

Comment: I do like the idea of using enums as suggested below. Unfortunately I do not have the ability to contact the original developers. I'll give the enum model a shot. Because the interface is not implemented anywhere in the code I don't forsee any immediate problems...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This (having dedicated interface for storing constants) was a fairly common way of storing constants before the era of enums. (Pre Java 5 times.) It saved you the hassle of prefixing your constants with the containing class name. I personally never really liked this practice, but this is the reason people did it.

As for what it can be replaced with:

1. An enum and a switch/case construct. This requires the least modification but only has modest benefits in readability. It does give you type and value safety, plus you can get warnings out of your IDE if you forget to handle a possible value (no `case` for it and no `default` block either).
2. A properties file. This obviously only works if you don't want to branch based on your constant values. (I.e. if your constants don't have to appear in your source code.) This is important, otherwise you'd end up with a secondary set of constants **and** a properties file, which is as bad as it gets.
3. A `doSomeStuff()` factory. For this you have to wrap your `doSomeStuff()` implementations in separate operation classes and you can configure your factory either statically or from a properties file. (via a constant value->operation class mapping). This is the most "enterprisey" solution, which means that although it looks nice and is very flexible, a lot of the time it is an overkill.

Comment: This makes sense. The package was coded before 1.5 was available. I think I'm going with the enum approach. In this case, the factory may be a little overkill, but might be worth considering in the future and the properties file solution presents the exact problem you've stated. thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I would consider using [`enums`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) instead as constants are **not** type safe (e.g., they are *just* ints, or strings, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

Use **enums**. Then get myenum.values() and then apply a for-each loop over the values.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good candidate for [enum](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 2):

Well, this looks like the Constant Interface antipattern and maybe should not be used. Using an enum might be a way as suggested, or at least using a final class with private constructor.

If you want to have different implementations for `doSomeStuff` based on the input string, you might also consider using the strategy pattern, i.e. have a `Map<String, Strategy>` and then lookup the strategy for `whatImLookingFor`. If you found the strategy, execute its `doSomeStuff`, otherwise handle the "not found" case.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a property file to store all your constants. This way you can load your properties into a HashMap as you suggest in your question.

Note that property support is brought natively with java: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: I like the idea of a property file, but our package is already utilizing quite a few. I think I would like to explore a class based solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, enums are the way to go ... but if the 'dosomestuff' is semantically dependent upon the specific value then why not add a 'dosomestuff' method to the enum itself. That is one that this is really great about Java enums - they are not merely data but as all good objects they have semantics. Then you just loop over the enums invoking dosomestuff(whatIamLookingFor) and whatever happens happens.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say. 
Yes, I agree, that it will be more elegant - at least for you. But think, what the next programmer will think about it. It will be even more complicated. 
Previously mentioned strategy pattern and java's enum are definitely better solution, but since you are maintaining this code, I'm not sure if your boss will be happy with time consuming refactoring. My advice would be to use enums - not so big code change.